# Jquery sortable using UP / Down button

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-sortable

I am trying to get sorted order list when user click on up/down button. Here is my demo  link I workout http://jsfiddle.net/prabud/qy89psbr/

```
function sendOrderToServer() {
  var items = $(".collection").sortable('toArray');
  var itemList = jQuery.grep(items, function(n, i){
                return (n !== "" && n != null);
        });
}

$(".collection").sortable({ items: ".item" });

$('button').click(function() { 
  var btn = $(this);
  var val = btn.val();
  if (val == 'up')
    moveUp(btn.parents('.item'));
  else
    moveDown(btn.parents('.item'));

  sendOrderToServer();
});
```

Finally I am getting wrong out and It's not in the user's selected order.

Please suggest me the right way to get sorted order list.

Comment: see the output after you click on down / up button.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because `animate` is an async function so your `sendOrderToServer` function will be fired before the animation complete.

You can move the function call inside the animate complete callback and it will work.

Code (of moveUp):

```
function moveUp(item) {
    var prev = item.prev();
    if (prev.length == 0) return;
    prev.css('z-index', 999).css('position', 'relative').animate({
        top: item.height()
    }, 250);
    item.css('z-index', 1000).css('position', 'relative').animate({
        top: '-' + prev.height()
    }, 300, function () {
        prev.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.css('z-index', '').css('top', '').css('position', '');
        item.insertBefore(prev);

        sendOrderToServer();
    });
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/IrvinDominin/bvvLurxa/

Answer (score 0):

Due to some reasons, I couldn't see the ids in the new order after change. I did the following changes to the JsFiddle to get ids & send them via ajax to server.

```
function sendOrderToServer() { 
    var arrayOfIds = $.map($(".item"), function(n, i){
      return n.id;
    });
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:  'sortable.php',
    dataType: "json",
    data: { 'item[]': arrayOfIds },
    success: function(data){
            /* Do something */
        }
    }); 
}
```