# ui-sortable in jquery get the latest value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui

I am working now for ui-sortable of jquery. I came by this link [Jquery sortable using UP / Down button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25978332/jquery-sortable-using-up-down-button). This question is a big help to me but I am new to jquery.

My problem is I created a button that when I clicked it should alert the latest sort structure but it doesn't alert (e.g 1,5,3,2,4). What did I missed.Please help me.

Below is the link:
http://jsfiddle.net/DharkRoses/gpjho4b7/2/

This is my the html:

```
<div class="collection">
    <div class="item" id="1">
    <div class="LeftFloat">Item1</div>
    <div class="RightFloat Commands">
        <button value='up'>Up</button>
        <button value='down'>Down</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="item" id="2">
    <div class="LeftFloat">Item2</div>
    <div class="RightFloat Commands">
        <button value='up'>Up</button>
        <button value='down'>Down</button>
    </div>
</div>

<button on-click = "newSortingOrder()">getNewOrder</button> //<-- The button I created.
```

The js file:

```
function newSortingOrder(){
   var order = orderList;
alert(order);
}
```

Comment: Your demo seems to work fine and doesn't contain button shown in question.

Comment: hi sorry I forgot to update my fiddle. I updated it now. pplease check

Comment: `on-click` should be `onclick` but your function as well as `orderList` aren't in global namespace due to load event function used in fiddle

Answer (score 0):

If you're already using jQuery, might aswell do the button click handling in JS aswell:

HTML:

```
<button id="gobutton">getNewOrder</button>
```

JS:

```
$("#gobutton").click(function() {
  var order = orderList;
  alert(order);
});
```

If you'd like to do it your way, i suggest changing "on-click" to "onClick" in HTML button tag.

Answer (score 0):

You can get latest sort structure by using this code

```
$( "#sortable" ).sortable('toArray');
```

It will returns an array of id attributes in the sorted order.